# Friction in a fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, friction, drag, flow, viscosity

when an object is moving in a fluid(air for example), the air will resist the object's movement: molecules of the air will collide with the surface of the object (no slip condition) and then we will have many layers of fluid "above" the surface of the object due to viscosity of the fluid. My question is: are the layers responsible for the friction between the air and the solid or it is just to the molecules that collide at the surface of the object or both?

Comment: Very few molecules actually collide with the object. At high speed one of the effects is that the fluid has to be pushed out of the way. Fluids thus have to change direction to flow around the object and since all ALL fluids have mass that means inertial forces have to be overcome ($F=ma$) and work has to be done. At low speeds inertial friction plays a smaller part and drag is mainly viscous. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number

Comment: Do you consider the layers made up of something other than air molecules? otherwise i don't understand your question. Friction in fluids is caused by molecules colliding with other molecules whether it be them hitting on a molecules in a solid surface or each other in layers. Clearly the molecules hitting the solid are the cause for friction which is transfered through the layers by viscosity; if you were to remove all solids in a homogeneous flowing domain there is by definition no friction between layers because there are no velocity gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to comment on question, need 50 rep. (why??)

I believe what you are referring to is viscosity in laminar flow. If I recall correctly, non-laminar flow is a precondition for turbulence, but I believe you can have viscosity which is not turbulent.

Is this the direction you had in mind?

**EDIT:**

1. Fluid molecules far away from the object will feel nothing.
2. Fluid molecules in the object's path will be pushed aside (and exert an equal and opposite force on the object).
3. As fluid molecules are pushed aside, they come into interaction with fluid close to the object path, and secondary interactions ensue.

So I think the answer to your question is: Both. Particles not in the object's path affect it indirectly, by causing those molecules directly in its path to escape less quickly. Imagine how the fluid density and molecular mass will affect the situation.

Comment: No, I am just asking who is responsible for friction on a solid flowing inside a fluid : Are the molecules that collide at the surface of the object (non-slip conditions) or it is the layers above the surface of the object or both? I am just asking because if the answer is both how the layers above the surface are applying force (friction) on the surface of the object?